# freeradius radacct table is empty and fortigate

Tags: radius, freeradius2

I configured freeradius with mysql and fortigate 
when I authorize one user every thing go fine but the radacct table is empty and there is no data was inserted into it 
I don't know where is the wrong even if I uncommented  sql int **/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default** 
in account , authorize and sesseion  section
 when I run  **freeradius -X** command the result into command line is

```
Going to the next request

Ready to process requests.

rad_recv: Accounting-Request packet from host 192.168.3.1 port 1029, id=28, length=102

           Acct-Status-Type = Start

        Acct-Session-Id = "0abf623e"

        User-Name = "zaib"

        NAS-Identifier = "ftg"

        Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.3.2

        Fortinet-Client-IP-Address = 192.168.3.2

        Fortinet-Vdom-Name = "root"

        Calling-Station-Id = "192.168.3.2"

        Event-Timestamp = "Jun 19 2017 13:21:57 +03"

        Acct-Delay-Time = 25

Executing section preacct from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default

+group preacct {

++[preprocess] = ok
[acct_unique] WARNING: Attribute NAS-Port was not found in request, unique ID 

MAY be inconsistent

[acct_unique] Hashing ',NAS-Identifier = "ftg",NAS-IP-Address = 

192.168.3.1,Acct-Session-Id = "0abf623e",User-Name = "zaib"'


[acct_unique] Acct-Unique-Session-ID = "e208d05f34bb9f17".

++[acct_unique] = ok

[suffix] No '@' in User-Name = "zaib", looking up realm NULL

[suffix] No such realm "NULL"

++[suffix] = noop

+} # group preacct = ok

 Executing section accounting from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default

+group accounting {

[detail]        expand: %{Packet-Src-IP-Address} -> 192.168.3.1

[detail]        expand: /var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-

%{Packet-Src-IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d -> 

/var/log/freeradius/radacct/192.168.3.1/detail-20170619


[detail] /var/log/freeradius/radacct/%{%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}:-%{Packet-Src-

IPv6-Address}}/detail-%Y%m%d expands to 

/var/log/freeradius/radacct/192.168.3.1/detail-20170619

[detail]        expand: %t -> Mon Jun 19 13:21:57 2017

++[detail] = ok

[radutmp]       expand: /var/log/freeradius/radutmp -> 

/var/log/freeradius/radutmp

[radutmp]       expand: %{User-Name} -> zaib

  rlm_radutmp: No NAS-Port seen.  Cannot do anything.

  rlm_radumtp: WARNING: checkrad will probably not work!

++[radutmp] = noop

[sradutmp]      expand: /var/log/freeradius/sradutmp -> 

/var/log/freeradius/sradutmp

[sradutmp]      expand: %{User-Name} -> zaib

  rlm_radutmp: No NAS-Port seen.  Cannot do anything.

  rlm_radumtp: WARNING: checkrad will probably not work!

++[sradutmp] = noop

rlm_checkval: Item Name: Calling-Station-Id, Value: 192.168.3.2

rlm_checkval: Could not find attribute named Calling-Station-Id in check pairs

++[checkval] = notfound

+} # group accounting = notfound

Finished request 12.

Cleaning up request 12 ID 28 with timestamp +59

Going to the next request
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling the sql module anywhere, so it's not inserting records into your database.  edit `raddb/sites-available/default`, look for the `accounting {}` section.

Find the call to sql with the hash in front of it `# sql`.  Remove the hash so the line is just `sql`.

Assuming you've configured the SQL module correctly, the server will now insert accounting records into your database.